# Beautiful Soup web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a product name and its price from one local website, for this I am using Beautiful Soup. My code:

```
productlinks = []
    
for x in range(1,5):
    r = requests.get(F'https://www.technodom.kz/bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/f/brands/lg/brands/samsung?page={x}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    productlist = soup.find_all('li', class_='ProductCard')
    for item in productlist:
            for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
                productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])
    print(productlinks)
```

The code does not work, it does not get product links, returns [] []

Could you please suggest a solution for this problem

Thank you for the feedback!

Now its getting product links, however it double counts each product ( I get 2 links for the same product), is there any solution for this? Also, after getting product links I need to get product information (e.g, Name and Price), for this I am using the code above, but again it double counts products and don't get the name and price.

```
 wmlist = []
for link in productlinks:
    driver.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    print(link)
    name = soup.find('h1', class_='ProductHeader-Title').text.strip()
    price = soup.find('p', class_='ProductPrice ProductInformation-Price').text.strip()

    wm = {
        'Model':name,
        'Price': price
    }
    wmlist.append(wm)
    print('Saving:', wm['Model'])
df = pd.DataFrame(wmlist)

df.to_excel("TD pricesTEST.xlsx", sheet_name='TEW', index=False)
```

Comment: Content ist generated dynamically, so you should use [Selenium Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website is loaded dynamically, therefore `requests` doesn't support it. Try using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

product_links = []
baseurl = "https://www.technodom.kz/"
options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe", options=options)


for x in range(1, 5):
    driver.get(
        f"https://www.technodom.kz/bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/f/brands/lg/brands/samsung?page={x}"
    )
    # Wait for the page to fully render
    sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    product_list = soup.find_all("li", class_="ProductCard")
    for item in product_list:
        for link in item.find_all("a", href=True):
            product_links.append(baseurl + link["href"])
    print(product_links)
```

Output:

```
['https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-12b8wds7-215024', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-12b8wds7-215024', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-lg-f-bnd-config/color-palette/belihy', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-lg-f-bnd-config/color-palette/belihy', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stir-mashina-samsung-ww-60k40g09wdlp-219705', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stir-mashina-samsung-ww-60k40g09wdlp-219705', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-ww-jeohwdld-165832', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-ww-jeohwdld-165832', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-lg-f-mhsw-136539', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-lg-f-mhsw-136539', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-ww-kewdld-113951', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-ww-kewdld-113951', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-ww-kesdld-113952', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-ww-kesdld-113952', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-lg-f-vhss-170387', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-lg-f-vhss-170387', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-s-suskoj-samsung-wd-wwrxtwdld-148026', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-s-suskoj-samsung-wd-wwrxtwdld-148026', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-lg-f-mhss-159900', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-lg-f-mhss-159900', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-1296hds4-215028', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-1296hds4-215028', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-ww-rxssdld-148185', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-ww-rxssdld-148185', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-samsung-ww-70j42g03wdld-216244', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-samsung-ww-70j42g03wdld-216244', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-1296nds3-215026', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-1296nds3-215026', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-wf-nlwdy-34836', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-wf-nlwdy-34836', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-1296hds0-212817', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-1296hds0-212817', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-lg-f-vhsw-170386', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-lg-f-vhsw-170386', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-1296wds0-215025', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-1296wds0-215025', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-2j6hg0w-141164', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-2j6hg0w-141164', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-2v3gs6w-219501', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-2v3gs6w-219501', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-ww-jeohsdld-165831', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-ww-jeohsdld-165831', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-2v5hs9b-219577', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-lg-f-2v5hs9b-219577', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-wf-frfwd-34835', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaa-masina-samsung-wf-frfwd-34835', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-samsung-ww-80t3040bw-ld-227819', 'https://www.technodom.kz//bytovaja-tehnika/uhod-za-odezhdoj/stiral-nye-mashiny/p/stiralnaya-mashina-samsung-ww-80t3040bw-ld-227819']
...
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Now its getting product links, however it double counts each product ( I get 2 links for the same product), is there any solution for this? Also, after getting product links I need to get product information (e.g, Name and Price), for this I am using the code above, but again it double counts products and don't get the name and price.

Comment: Could you help with another issue that I mentioned above.